# Missing Cycles render engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

[image]

When trying to switch from Eevee to Cycles I discovered that there is no Cycles render engine setting on my blender!

I'm using version 2.92. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

When I search for cycles this is what comes up.

Comment: Hello and welcome. What OS are you using and where did you get Blender? (website, steam, app store, etc)

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and I got my copy of Blender from blender.org. I am updating to the latest version of Blender now (2.93.2).

Comment: SOLUTION: updating to the latest version solved my problem! Thank you Emir for commenting :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: updating to the latest version solved my problem.

Comment: The Cycles render engine is actually an addon in Blender so it's possible that it wasn't enabled for some strange reason although the entry is usually checked by default on the Preferences > Addons tab..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Cycles is enabled in Preferences ► Add-ons:

[image]